# Confusion on commutativity of matrices/operators in a given proof: $(T-\mu I)(T-\lambda I)^{p-1}(x)$ = $(T-\lambda I)^{p-1}(T-\mu I)(x)$ = $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

The proof is given in a linear algebra textbook for the proposition:

> Let T be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $λ$
>   be an eigenvalue of $T$.
>   Then for any scalar $μ  \ne λ$, the restriction of $T − μI$ to $K_{λ}$ is one-to-one.

And the proof is provided:

> Let $x ∈ K_{λ}$ and $(T − μI)(x) = 0$. By way of contradiction, suppose
>   that $x \ne 0$. Let $p$ be the smallest integer for which $(T−λI) p (x) = 0$, and let
>   $y = (T − λI)^{p−1} (x)$.
>
> Then $(T − λI)(y)$ = $(T − λI)^{p}(x) = 0$,
>   and hence $y ∈ E_{λ}$ . Furthermore,
>
> > $(T-\mu I)(T-\lambda I)^{p-1}(x) = (T-\lambda I)^{p-1}(T-\mu I)(x)$ = $0$

To be fair I've read a few other duplicate questions on the site and people provide very reasonable and quite obvious explanations that:

1. by induction on $p$, this works
2. $T$ can be written as $(T−λI)+λI$ hence, again, they commute
3. $T$ commutes with both $T$ and $λI$, $T$ commutes with  $T−λId$ and therefore it commutes with any power of $T−λId$.
4. just binomial expansion of $LHS$ and $RHS$ would make this apparent

And I *am* convinced at this point, but decided to still ask because I've never seen so many similar questions on this formulation( on this book's Stephen H. Friedberg).

I think most of my confusion came from the fact that when I see $ (T - \lambda I)(x)$ I implicitly think of it as a matrix and we were often cautioned in the previous courses that matrices do *NOT* commute.

What is the most correct way to get out of this bind: should I tell myself that both $T$ and $I$ really do not *have* to be matrices in this formulation and are just arbitrary operators? Or is it less incorrect to say that matrices don't commute *in general*, but some particular -- do.

I realize this might be pretty solipsistic for such a simple question, but would still appreciate if somebody with the right intuitions weighed in. Non-esoteric (counter)examples are especially appreciated :)

Comment: Because multiplication is associative, powers of $T$ commute with each other: $T^n T^m = T^{n + m} = T^m T^n$. In particular, this also works for $T^0 = I$. Put this together with addition and scalar multiplication to find that if $p$ and $q$ are any polynomials, then $p(T) q(T) = q(T) p(T)$ (which you can argue by expanding into powers of $T$ on either side). So any time you see expressions involving linear combinations of powers of $T$ and the identity, they will commute with other such expressions. This argument works for general linear operators just as well as it does for matrices.

Comment: When we say that matrices don't commute, we mean that  "$AB=BA$ for any two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$" is a false statement.  I.e. there are two matrices such that $AB \neq BA$.  This doesn't imply that $AB\neq BA$ for all such matrices (which would be wrong, see, e.g. the study of simultaneously diagonalizable matrices)

Comment: The more general intuition is if you have a collection of linear operators $A, B, C, \ldots$ which all commute pairwise, then you are free to rearrange any expression in these (or powers of these) however you like, treating it as a polynomial in *variables* $A, B, C, \ldots$. So for example $(AB + C - 2I)A^2 = A^2(BA + C - 2I)$ holds.